# Synchronizing N Values Accross Tables in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, field, synchronize

Disclaimer: I just started with databases, so I'm probably missing something extremely trivial.

I have two (somewhat related, but not enough to be a single table) tables: `table_one` and `table_two`.

---

`table_one` has two columns of significance:

1. `name` of type `varchar(n)`
2. `intersects` of type `bit`

`table_two` has one column of significance:

1. `name` of type `varchar(n)`

---

I would like to **automatically** set `intersects` to either `0` or `1` depending on whether `name` is present in `table_two`.

Can I somehow delegate this responsibility to the database engine? I'm currently using MySQL, if that matters.

---

**EDIT:** Does this sort of close-coupling even make sense when dealing with databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI SQL:

```
update table_one
set intersects = 
    case when 
        (select count(*) from table_two where name = table_one.name) > 0 
        then 1 
    else 0 end
```

MySQL Join:

```
update table_one t1
    left join table_two t2 on
        t1.name = t2.name
set t1.intersects = case when t2.name is not null then 1 else 0 end
```

You can put this query into a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to keep `intersects` up-to-date:

```
create trigger intersections after insert for each row
begin

    update table_one t1
        left join table_two t2 on
            t1.name = t2.name
    set t1.intersects = case when t2.name is not null then 1 else 0 end
    where t1.name = new.name

end
```

Now, for the design discussion:

An `intersects` column is great and all, but you may run into the issue where it gets out of sync. What you can do is use an `exists` function in your `select` when calling this:

```
select
    *
from
    table_one t1
where
    exists (select 1 from table_two t2 where t2.name = t1.name)
```

You can use `not exists` to find those that don't intersect, as well.

Moreover, you can also use a `left join` to pull back both cases:

```
select
    *
from
    table_one t1
    left join table_two t2 on
        t1.name = t2.name
```

Anything where `t2.name` is `null`, you don't have an intersection. Anything where it isn't, you do. Of course, this can produce duplicate rows if you don't have a `unique` constraint on `name`.

Hopefully this sheds some light on all of this!

Comment: Thank you Eric, would I have to execute this query every single time there is a change to table_one? Is there some way to register a callback of sorts that gets called when a table modification occurs?

Comment: By callback, I don't mean in my application, I mean in the database itself.

Comment: ansi and mysql... +1 for knowing the ansi!

Comment: @Vulcanus: "Trigger" is the callback you are looking for.